# Sort by row one, row two & row three in an ascending order using np.array list with an 2 Dimensional Array in python

Tags: arrays, numpy, sorting, swap

I need to sort it by first row 1, row 2 & row 3 in ascending order using np.array list

```
*Input*

[[9, 3, 2], [4, 0, 1], [5, 8, 6]]

*Expected output* 

[[4 0 1]
 [5 8 6]
 [9 3 2]]

Using the below logics gets partially correct 

array_test = np.array(input_list)
array_res=np.sort(input_list, axis=0)
Please correct my logics

I need to sort it by first row 1, row 2 & row 3 in ascending order using 
np.array list 

Ascending order by entire full row wise 401, 586, 932 should be appears 
using numpy-array sort
```

Comment: Ascending order by entire full row wise 401, 586, 932 should be appears using numpy-array sort

Comment: Using the below logics gets partially correct                                                                 array_test = np.array(input_list)
array_res=np.sort(input_list, axis=0)